# Dreamweaver hotspot

Tags: css, coding-style, dreamweaver

Can I apply css style to dreamweaver hotspot? what I mean is to change backcolor,size,font  size, etc...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hotspots, at least in my experience, are just the areas you define on an image that can be clickable.  In HTML they add a map element to your code, assign that map to the image, and add area elements within the map element defining the region that is clickable.  (see here:  http://www.entheosweb.com/website_design/image_maps.asp)

In that case, you can't do much to control that area element with CSS.

If you're talking about hyperlinks (the  element), then yes you can do all of the above.  For example:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: Red;
    font-size: 24pt;    
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want an easy way  to style the message that appears when you hover over a hotspot, you can use this jQuery plug-in: [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Comment: What i meant is that when i create a hotspot like this <area shape="rect" coords="133,297,212,315" href="#" title=hello>
a little yellow windows opens with word "hello" when I hover, so i want to apply style for this window.

Comment: @Sundance - Funny, I just had this same thing come up a few weeks ago.  See my answer update.  There's a nice jquery plugin that can help you.